# Does CoD World at War Zombies mode support co-op gameplay on PC?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war, cod-world-at-war-zombies

CoD World at War is currently available at an attractive price, perfect for a two player game session!

Is zombie mode available to coop game play, like it is for console games?

Furthermore, is it possible to play the zombie maps in multi-player mode right after purchasing the game, without having to complete the single player campaign first?

To clarify the second question - Some forum comments suggest completing single player gameplay is required to unlock zombie mode. Is this the case? The zombie mode is probably the most entertaining multiplayer mode, hence I'm keen to get started straight away.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the WaW steam page, to see what the reviews are like and it seems as though co-op should still be functional.

People who have recently purchased the game have praised the co-op element so you should be able to play co-op and multiplayer.

You may have to manually search for servers, as I'm unsure as to whether the game still has built in server support from the developers.